# Use multicriteria method with clustering

Tags: clustering, multicriteria-decision-analysis

I created a clustering algorithm to determine the optimal number of clusters from a dataset that has information on rural properties. I use hierarchical agglomerative clustering for this. Basically, I use two criteria for generating these clusters, which is production of waste from properties and logistical costs. However, I see the need to consider integrating other approaches to evaluating the optimal number of clusters to improve reliability. I thought about using some multicriteria method, but I don't know which one to use, any tips?

Comment: There are some useful articles around this topic. For example, [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S187705091200261X) and [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/223649076_Towards_multicriteria_clustering_An_extension_of_the_k-means_algorithm) might be helpful. Do you see them?

Comment: I will check now @A.Omidi, thank for this!

Comment: Crossposted on Stats.SE (Cross Validated):  [Use multicriteria method with clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/562785/177387)